# How to set state to oidc-client-js in aurelia js

Tags: aurelia, oidc-client-js, aurelia-auth

I want to add state while initiating login.

tried this way :

```
let obj = {state: 'customurl'};
usermanager.signinRedirect(obj);
```

and extracting :

```
usermanager.signinRedirectCallback().then(res => { res.state });
```

this is returning 'undefined'.

please assist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
signinRedirect({ state: { bar: 15 } }); //Generates 15 char state value.

Comment: No, still its not working,it is showing undefined, I want to pass some url as current state and want to use that state after login successful. but it only returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to get is the `res.state` in the chain `then(res => { res.state })`, then you just need to remove the `{ }` wrapping the `res.state`.